# Where is the serialization going wrong?

Tags: c++, string, serialization

```
    void  insert_into_stream(std::ostream& stream,  int number)
{
    int length = sizeof(int);
    char insert_buffer[sizeof(int)];
    memcpy(insert_buffer, &number, length);
    stream.write(insert_buffer, length);
}

int int_from_string(std::string string)
{
    int a; 
    std::istringstream(string)>>a;
    return a;
}
```

This code used to work before, I don't remember what slight change I did and it isn't working anymore.
When a number (for example, 8001) comes in, and I'm debugging just before the last statement, insert_buffer contains 'A', so obviously something is going wrong and the 2nd function doesn't retrieve 8001.

Note - I do convert the stream to a string before sending it to the 2nd function.

Where is the first function wrong?

---edit----

Yes, I was wrong, the first function is actually doing exactly what it should, the second is wrong, can anyone please fix that?

Comment: `std::istringstream(string)>>a;` does that work?

Comment: yes it used, I cant test it right now, as the string anyways has false value

Comment: the second function, I got it from SO itself

Comment: Define "going wrong"? Doesn't compile? Doesn't give the right output? Throws exception?

Comment: The second function was never called and would only work with c++11. What is the expected result? The string "8001"?

Comment: "The first function is doing exactly what it should": you mean, write data that can only be read by the processes running on the same machine, compiled with the same compiler, using the same options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two functions are doing completely different things.

The first function is writing out the raw binary representation of an integer to a stream.

You have just copied the bits, this is the correct thing to do if you are serialising out to a binary file.

To convert it back, you would have to read in those 4 bytes, and cast that into an integer, just like you're doing the other way round.

Of course when you examine the characters they're going to be a one byte ascii representation of the integer bits. So 'A' is a perfectly reasonable thing to be there, as is anything else as it is entirely meaningless.

The second function however, is doing an ASCII Number to Integer number conversion. i.e. `atoi`.  This is meaningless for what you're trying to do as the characters aren't ascii numbers, they're binary integer numbers.

Edit for edit: You want something like this, just the opposite of what you did above.

```
int int_from_string(const char* number)
{
    int a; 
    memcpy(&a, number, sizeof(int));
    return a;
}
```

Comment: See my edit to my answer

Comment: hey BTW how can I contact you, I had a personal C++ question related to software engineering at investment banks

Comment: The first function is _not_ the correct thing to do when serializing out to a binary file.  The correct thing to do is format a buffer with the data according to the desired format, and output that.

Comment: @JamesKanze is right, by correct I meant it was functioning correctly, not that it was the best practice.

Comment: can u explain in bit more detail james, I didnt really understand you

Comment: `return *reinterpret_cast<const int*>(number)` would be more concise IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```c++
stream.write((const char*)&number, sizeof(number));
```

It's much shorter and you can also change the type of *number* and it will work (For simple types).

Comment: Shorter or not, it doesn't work any better than his original code.  Where do people get the idea that just dumping bits to a file will result in something that can be read later.